# How to change content of div using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi I am building an HTML site & to place ads inside that I need a javascript code to change it or update it from on script page not by going every page & cut/paste that ad code. I entered this in script page `document.getElementById.('adcode').innerHTML('HTML code provided by ad networks');`
 And in my website I used this code `<div id="adcode"> </div>`
But it is not showing anything even if I entered any other HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('adcode').innerHTML = 'HTML code provided by ad networks';
```

`innerHTML` is not a function, it is a variable. ALso, you had a `.` after `getElementById`.

A better way, however, would be something like this:

```
var text = document.createTextNode('HTML code provided by ad networks');
document.getElementById('adcode').appendChild(text);
```

If you use this method, the text will be automatically escaped for you.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why innerHTML is bad? It may not be in the DOM standard, but it clearly is a de-facto standard.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine It's still better to conform to standards, and furthermore `createTextNode` does escaping for you.

Comment: [**Non standard?**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0)

Comment: still not working 4 me. Listen again I want to ad it from one location  and to inside all of my webpages.

Comment: @Mayuresh Umm... I don't understand what you're saying. Doesn't this add the text that you want?

Comment: @Doorknob and IE8 and lower support `.innerHTML`, in fact `innerHTML` is IE innovation from the beginning.

Comment: @Esailija et.al. Okay, I guess the non-standard-ness doesn't really matter. Edited answer.

Comment: atleast tell me is there any way to force document.write to write anything inside of perticular div?